# Инициализация переменных сессии

Tags: php, переменные, сессия

А что, неинициализированные переменные сессии вызывают исключения при работе скрипта? Что-то я об этом нигде не слышал - а вот залил сайт на хостинг и пошли проблемы. Обязательно ли объявлять переменные через `session_register()`?

Comment: опишите какие именно проблемы, возможно дело не в этом

Comment: У меня в форме поля заполняются сессионными переменными : 
<input type="text" value=<?=$_SESSION['text']?>>
Переменная эта изначально не инициализирована, по идее просто ничего не должно выводится, а на самом деле выводится типа <br />
<br />:  Undefined index: text in mySite.php on line

Comment: @Deus, по идее, вы как раз и должны получать ошибку об неопределенном ключе массива.

Comment: Что делать - наверное так?
`session_start();
$_SESSION['text'] = "";`
Т.е. все переменные сессии изначально определить?

Comment: либо запрашивать их как-то так: ``<?=isset($_SESSION['text'])?$_SESSION['text']:''?>``

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Undefined index: text in mySite.php on line** - это не ошибка. Интерпретатор PHP просто выводит предупреждение о том, что переменная не определенна (точнее, что нет такого индекса, как "text" в массиве $_SESSION).

Так же интерпретатор просто обязан предупредить о наличии подобной ошибки, а вы со своей стороны просто ОБЯЗАНЫ делать что-то вроде

```
if(isset($_SESSION['text']))
{
//вывод значения
}
else
{
// вывод пустой строки
}
```

Comment: Спасибо, честно говоря, никто не предупредил меня об этом, я думал, что пхп настолько гибок, что если переменная не определена, он просто ничего не выводит. Без всяких ошибок и предупреждений

Comment: Впрочем я занимался по книгам. А там половины недосказывают

Comment: @Deus, выбросите эти книги и возьмите какие-нибудь другие.

Comment: Я это давно уже сделал.

Answer (score 0):

теперь всё ясно, вы пытаетесь обратиться к не объявленному элементу массива.
Ни каких "по идее" тут быть не может. Выполняйте проверки перед выводом через `isset($_SESSION['text'])`

старайтесь не хранить в сессиях что попало и контролировать наличие переменных с которыми работаете

---

```
 <input type="text" value="<?=(isset($_SESSION['text'])?$_SESSION['text']:'')?>">
```

Comment: @KryDos, опередили. ну пусть теперь будет )

Comment: @Gedweb, а ваш ответ даже симпатичнее :) Тернарный оператор выглядит гораздо короче моего варианта.